# How would you type hint Dict in Python with constant form but multiple types?

Tags: python, list, type-hinting, typing

I want to type hint the return object of some_func function, which is always the same format. Is this correct?

```
from typing import List, Dict


def some_func() -> List[Dict[str, int, str, List[CustomObject]]]:
    my_list = [
               {"ID": 1, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]}
               ]
    return my_list
```

Comment: You are looking for a [TypedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy set dictionary keys / interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648538/mypy-set-dictionary-keys-interface)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way of correctly type hinting would look like this:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Union

def some_func() -> List[Dict[str, Union[int, List[CustomObject]]]]:
    my_list = [
               {"ID": 1, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]}
               ]
    return my_list
```

for a brief explanation, when type annotating a dict, you can only have two arguments, the first being the type of any given key, and the second, the type of any given value.
since keys are always strings, we keep `Dict[str,` and our keys can be either an integer, or of type CustomObject, to represent different possibilities in type annotations we use `Union`, and so in the end we get:

```
Dict[str, Union[int, List[CustomObject]]
```

for some additional notes, in python 3.9 or above you may replace `Dict` imported from typing, with the builtin `dict`, and in python 3.10 or above, unions can be represented as `type | type`, and you can replace `List` with the builtin `list`

for a cleaner result you may want to use a typedDict, the overall result would be:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class customDict(TypedDict):
    ID: int
    cargo: list[CustomObject]

def some_func() -> list[customDict]:
    my_list = [
               {"ID": 1, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]},
               {"ID": 2, "cargo": [CustomObject(), CustomObject()]}
               ]
    return my_list
```

each property of the typed dict represents a key of the dicts in my_list, and the following reprents the type of value related to the key

Comment: `Union` should use `[]` instead of `()`.

Comment: Replacing `Union` with `|` is in PEP604 https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict):

```py
class MyDict(TypedDict):
    ID: int
    cargo: list[CustomObject]

def some_func()->list[MyDict]:
    pass
```

A typed dict, see [PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/) is a way to specify different types for different keys in a dict.

Also note that since python 3.10 you can just use `list[type]` instead of `typing.List[type]`. Works for dicts and tuples too.